# Vim python code formatting

Tags: vim

I'm using the plugin [auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) to help auto close brackets.

In vim when defining dicts or lists it'll auto formatting like this

`|` is the cursor position

```
a_dict = {
        | # the indent is 8 spaces width, but I already set 4 spaces width indent in .vimrc
        }

a_lst = [
        |
        ]

a_lst_with_a_very_loooooooooooong_name = [
        |
        ]
```

but I want it formats the code like this

```
lst = [
    |
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Tried other plugins, works fine with them but they all pale in comparison to auto-pairs. Did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

For Python indenting in vim, I use [this plugin for pep8 indentation](https://github.com/hynek/vim-python-pep8-indent) with [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle). This plugin works with yours and gives you the functionality you want (at least on my machine)

Example:

```
lst = [
    |
]

abc = {
    |
}
```

You especially want the `let g:pymode_indent = 0` line in your .vimrc for the pep8 plugin.

Someone who is skilled in vim programming might be able to modify your plugin to do what you need, but this solution might bring you another benefits if you use vim for Python programming.

To address your issue with 8 spaces as a tab - try having all

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
filetype indent on
```

in your .vimrc (this is what I have and it gives me 4 spaces indentation)

Comment: Sweet googly moogly this had me tearing my hair out - the plugin solves the issue